# How can I create a chatbot that organizes input into selected templates?

Tags: chatbot

I want to create a chatbot that asks questions that, according to their answers, travel down a tree of templates. I'm not very experienced in the coding world, so excuse me if my jargon isn't right!

Here's an example.

I want to write custom reports based on a user's input into a chatbot. Let's imagine the user wants some daily, custom motivation.

How are you feeling today?
Based on user inputs this is categorized into:
"GOOD - BAD - SAD - HAPPY - EXCITED" etc...

Depending on which one, we travel down a "template tree," so any templates that would exist under the "BAD" category are disregarded if the user writes "Pretty Good" and it's categorized as "Good."

Then we ask questions like, "What's your name?", that are stored as variables to incorporate into a text template once we find the right template based on their inputs.

What's the best platform to build this? Is it indeed a chatbot?

Thank you so much for the help!

I tried Pandorabots but it seems too linear - as in a input > response model, there's not much conditional logic. I'm ready to research and learn, so any tips on which platform / approach would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Pandorabots uses AIML to create a chatbot and you can certainly do conditional logic in it. Here's some code that will solve your request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aiml version="2.0">

<category>
    <pattern>HI</pattern>
    <template>
        Hi there. What is your name?
    </template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>*</pattern>
    <that>WHAT IS YOUR NAME</that>
    <template>
        <think><set name="name"><star/></set></think>
        How are you feeling today?
    </template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>*</pattern>
    <that>HOW ARE YOU FEELING TODAY</that>
    <template>
        <think><set name="mood"><star/></set></think>
        <condition name="mood">
            <li value="good">That's great <get name="name"/>.</li>
            <li value="bad">Sorry to hear that <get name="name"/>. Can I help?</li>
            <li value="sad">Cheer up <get name="name"/>, it's a beautiful day!</li>
            <li value="happy">Oh wow <get name="name"/>. I'm so pleased for you!</li>
            <li value="excited">Amazing <get name="name"/>! What's happened?</li>
            <li>The day is yours to command <get name="name"/>.</li>
        </condition>
    </template>
</category>

</aiml>
```

A sample conversation would look like this:

[image]

Using the pattern side  tag, you can also do this with Pandorabots to group similar answers together. Create sets called "good" and "bad" with all the emotions that should trigger the templates. Example of the "good" set:

```
[
    ["amazing"],
    ["good"],
    ["happy"],
    ["great"]
]
```

And then use a categories like this:

```
<category>
    <pattern>I FEEL <set>good</set></pattern>
    <template>Great to hear!</template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>I FEEL <set>bad</set></pattern>
    <template>Sorry to hear that. Can I help?</template>
</category>
```

Hope that helps. Pandorabots is capable of FAR more than input - response and I've won the Loebner Prize 4 times for having the world's most humanlike conversational AI using AIML and Pandorabots.

Comment: Have you really won the prize 4 times? Is there any version of your bots online?

Comment: Yes. I have a version of Mitsuku available to talk to at http://www.mitsuku.com
This is not the same version that won the Loebner Prize and doesn't think it's human.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I've met up with Steve and he knows what he's talking about!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already tried Pandorabots then I assume you are familiar with XML and aiml, that's why I am proposing program O [Program  O on Github](https://github.com/Program-O/Program-O) 
aiml has a functionality call  which can be used to build interactive tree chats.
check my example below. though I guess you might have come across aiml in your research.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
  <aiml version = "1.0.1" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
    <category>
      <pattern>hi</pattern>
      <template>How are you feeling today?</template>  
    </category>

    <category>
      <pattern>GOOD</pattern>
      <that>How are you feeling today?</that>
      <template>Nice, I like it that way.</template>
   </category>

   <category>
     <pattern>BAD</pattern>
     <that>How are you feeling today?</that>
     <template>
       <randon>
         <li>Ok! I think you need an appointment with a doctor?</li
         <li>How exactly are you feeling?</li>
      </random>       
    </template>
  </category> 

  <category>
    <pattern>SAD_</pattern>
    <that>How are you feeling today?</that>
    <template>
     <randon>
       <li>Ok! what happened?</li
       <li>how can i help?</li>
     </random>       
    </template>
  </category>

  <category>
   <pattern>HAPPY_</pattern>
   <that>How are you feeling today?</that>
   <template>
   <randon>
     <li>great! its good for you</li
     <li>thats what up.</li>
    </random>       
   </template>
 </category>
</aiml>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Bruce! I haven't yet learned much XML and AIML, but if you recommend this is the best route to go down, then I will commit to learning and applying it. Thanks!